# Get the main thread from a secondary thread

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, unix, pthreads

I have code that is loaded into a 3rd party program for which I do not have the source. The program occasionally hangs and after debugging it with disassembly, I have traced it to be due to a race condition between the locking order of two mutexes in the main thread and the thread hosting my plugin. The calls locking the mutexes are both in OSX frameworks.

I want to see if pausing the main thread, while my plugin thread continues, will allow the program not to cause a deadlock.

I can get the list of threads with a calls to **task_info** and **task_threads**, but this requires calling **task_for_pid**, which only works if the program is run as root, or a member of the procmod group. This is not an option.

So, is it possible to get the main thread (as a **thread_t**) and suspend it from a secondary thread, without the need for the main application to be running as root?

Comment: This smells like the wrong way of doing things.  Are you completely sure that the deadlock is being caused by two locks from the OS and that you have no stack frames of your own code in the middle to control the locking order?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, yes completely sure. Both threads want both locks, but acquire them in the opposite order. It results in a lock up occasionally, due to the race condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm deeply dubious about what you claim is going on and also your plan for working around it, but…

You can use a condition lock to coordinate.  The lock starts in condition 1.  Submit a task asynchronously to the main thread, have it lock the lock when in condition 1 and then unlock it in condition 2.  It then attempts to lock it in condition 3, which will cause it to block.  Your background thread can lock the lock in condition 2, so it will wait for the main thread to be blocked.  It does its work and then unlocks the lock in condition 3.

```
NSConditionLock* lock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:1];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [lock lockWhenCondition:1];
    [lock unlockWithCondition:2];
    [lock lockWhenCondition:3];
});
[lock lockWhenCondition:2];
// ... do work ...
[lock unlockWithCondition:3];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm currently working on getting a small, reproducible project to demonstrate the issue, which I'll make available when it's done. The code you presented looks like a good solution, though it will mean converting my project to use Objective-C too; currently the plugin is just C.

Comment: You can use pthreads conditions and mutexes instead, although it won't be as straightforward. Or maybe a pair of dispatch semaphores.